# Send an attachment in gmail with logic app failed

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that needs to read data from a file on ADLS, take content, and that content sent as an attachment using Gmail. 
I see from logic app documentation that size of attachment in Gmail is 30mb ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/gmail/ ), so I have a condition if the file size is bigger than 20MB don't send an e-mail (send some information about bad request). But my logic app still failed on send e mail action. Even if attachment size is < 20MB.

> Error message:"*Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine*"

I am guessing it's something with SMTP protocol, not the Gmail connector. Does anybody have the same problem? Is there some workaround?

Comment: Have you tried with smaller attachment sizes to see if it works? It could be that the download/upload takes too long.

Comment: yes, it works with size<=10MB. That executes in 5sec. So it's not so clear to me why it failed when size is between 10 and 20 MB